# How to make traefik use wildcard certificates for multiple subdomains from dyamic configuration file?

Tags: traefik

We have a wild-card certificate from siteground which is used for multiple sub-domains like

```
test.example.com
apis.example.com
dev.exmaple.com
stg.example.com
etc
```

We have created 'A' record for `test.example.com` like `*.test.example.com` pointing to particular server to create dynamic routes using traefik proxy services.

```
type   Name                value
  A    *.test.example.com  xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

Dynamically created routes are working as expected, HTTP to HTTPS redirection is also working fine as well as basic-auth.

Below is the configuration files.

```
# docker-compose.yml file

version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.6"
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --providers.docker
      - --api
      - --providers.file.directory=/configuration/
      - --providers.file.watch=true

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/apps/test2/configuration/:/configuration/"
      - "/apps/test2/certs/:/etc/certs/"
    labels:
      # Dashboard
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.test.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=authtraefik"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authtraefik.basicauth.users=user:$$apr1$$q8eZFHjF$$Fvmkk//V6Btlaf2i/ju5n/" # user/password
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.domains[0].main=test.example.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.domains[0].sans=*.test.example.com"
      
      # global redirect to https
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"

      # middleware redirect
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"

  my-app:
    image: traefik/whoami:v1.7.1
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.rule=Host(`whoami.test.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=user:$$apr1$$q8eZFHjF$$Fvmkk//V6Btlaf2i/ju5n/" # user/password
```

```
# configuration/config.yml 
# Dynamic configuration
tls:
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: /etc/certs/cert.cert
        keyFile: /etc/certs/cert.key
```

But SSL is not working for dynamic routes like `whoami.test.example.com` instead its generating/using a self-signed certificate instead of the above-passed certificate while the certificate is working perfectly for static sub-domain `test.example.com`.

So how to make traefik use that wild card certificate for all the dynamically created sub-domains for this wildcard domain entry `*.test.exmaple.com`  using traefik's dynamic file configuration settings as our domain provider's name is not there in traefik's providers list like ``` Cloudflare, GoDaddy, Namecheap etc``